# Memory leaks (_CrtSetReportMode()/_CrtSetDbgFlag())

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, memory-leaks

While hunting memory leaks by _CrtSetReportMode()/_CrtSetDbgFlag() function combination, is there any chance not to dump all blocks unfreed, but just a number of unfreed blocks? So to produce compactness output?

Comment: Scary request.  I suppose you could use _CrtSetReportHook2() and just count messages.

Comment: OK, it seems, that's what I need